# Polymer Slider Automation using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: javascript, selenium, slider, polymer

I have to automate a Slider that has been build using polymer UI.
The current code using Actions works fine in Chrome version 35 but fails to drag and drop slider while executing testing in higher chrome versions.I did some research but couldn't find a suitable answer on how this can be fixed. What I have found is, it would need Javascript to fix the issue. 
Can someone share the Javascript that could help me? Let me know if you need additional details from me.
Note: I have already tried Actions and Robot that aren't helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

/**
         * This function will drag and drop the sourceElement till targetElement
         * @param sourceElement
         * @param targetElement
         */
        public void sliderDragDrop(WebElement sourceElement,WebElement targetElement)
        {
            int xdraggerObj=sourceElement.getLocation().x;
            int ydraggerObj=sourceElement.getLocation().y;

```
        int xLocatorTo=targetElement.getLocation().x;
        int yLocatorTo=targetElement.getLocation().y;

        String xTo=Integer.toString(xLocatorTo-xdraggerObj);
        String yTo=Integer.toString(yLocatorTo-ydraggerObj);  

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
            "function simulate(f,c,d,e){var b,a=null;for(b in eventMatchers)if(eventMatchers[b].test(c)){a=b;break}if(!a)return!1;document.createEvent?(b=document.createEvent(a),a==\"HTMLEvents\"?b.initEvent(c,!0,!0):b.initMouseEvent(c,!0,!0,document.defaultView,0,d,e,d,e,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),f.dispatchEvent(b)):(a=document.createEventObject(),a.detail=0,a.screenX=d,a.screenY=e,a.clientX=d,a.clientY=e,a.ctrlKey=!1,a.altKey=!1,a.shiftKey=!1,a.metaKey=!1,a.button=1,f.fireEvent(\"on\"+c,a));return!0} var eventMatchers={HTMLEvents:/^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,MouseEvents:/^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/}; "
                    + "simulate(arguments[0],\"mousedown\",0,0); simulate(arguments[0],\"mousemove\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); simulate(arguments[0],\"mouseup\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); ",
            sourceElement, xTo, yTo);
    }
```